# C converting user entered real time to unix time

Tags: c, unix

I'm supposed to convert a date the user entered through stdin to unix time. We are only interested in the date, not the current time, that's why I set tm_hour, tm_min and tm_sec to zero.

My code seems to work okay but it is missing 3600 seconds in order to be right. When I enter the date 1.1.1970 shouldn't it print out 0?

So why do I have to add 3600 to get the right result?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main() {

    time_t tnow = 0;
    struct tm *tmnow;

    int year, month, day;

    printf("Bitte gib das Jahr an: "); // Input year
    scanf("%d", &year);
    printf("Bitte gib den Monat an: "); // Input month
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("Bitte gib den Tag an: "); // Input day
    scanf("%d", &day);

    tmnow->tm_year = (year-1900);
    tmnow->tm_mon = (month-1);
    tmnow->tm_mday = day;
    tmnow->tm_hour = 0;
    tmnow->tm_min = 0;
    tmnow->tm_sec = 0;

    tnow = mktime(tmnow);
    tnow += 3600; // WHY??
    printf("%d\n", tnow);
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are in Germany, then you need to add 1 hour.

Comment: `mktime` takes in the time in **localtime**. The 0 seconds is UTC time. Even in 1970 all of Germany was at GMT+1.